# How to write result of a differentiation in terms of dependent variable?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

It seems likely that the question is a close duplicate of some other answer, but I can find it so---

Suppose I want to differentiate $\sin(x)$. The answer is $\cos(x)$. But I want the answer to be written in terms of $\sin(x)$ that is $\sqrt{1-\sin^2{x}}$ . How can I do this in Mathematica? I am doubting we have to use `ReplaceAll` or Substitute but I don't know how as I am new to Mathematica :)

Comment: `Cos[x] /. Cos -> (Sqrt[1 - Sin[#]^2] &)`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a build-in way., If you do not want to do global replace on the expression, you could add your own transformation to Simplify and use Simplify instead.

```
t[e_] := Which[Head[e] == Cos, Sqrt[1 - Sin[First@e]^2], _, e];
f[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Cos, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e];
Simplify[Cos[x], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t}, ComplexityFunction -> f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[Sin[x] + Cos[x],TransformationFunctions ->{Automatic, t},ComplexityFunction->f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[1+Cos[x]^2, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t}, ComplexityFunction -> f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and so on.

So when you get your solution, just call `Simplify` on it, but using the above code, it will replace each $\cos(x)$ with what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that
$${d\over dx} \sin x = \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$$
is incorrect unless $x$ measures an angle lying in quadrant I or IV.  The OP doesn't address this, but one can work with this hypothesis as follows.

```
First@ Normal@ SolveValues[
    {s' == D[Sin[x], x], s == Sin[x], s' >= 0},
    s',
    {x},    (* eliminate x *)
    Reals] /. s -> Sin[x]
```

> ```
> (*
>   Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]^2]
> *)
> ```